# TYPO3 Extbase: Set storagepid for Backend Module

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have written a small extension that provide news for Backend User. 
Ist is just 2 Parts. One part showing the news for all BE User as a own Module, and the other part are create and edit functions provided by the TCA.

To work with the TCA forms and the default extbase getter, i need the correct storagePid. I can't set them via TypoScript, because **I'm never in a page context**.

My Idea was to use the Plugin settings with the file `ext_conf_template.txt`

```
# cat=persistence/enable; type=int; label=Storage pid
storagePid = 4457
```

[image: settings]

But how can I tell TYPO3 to look at this Settings?

At least `Repository->findAll()` must respect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but it works.

I have written my own function in the repository with the pid as parameter.
I'm using the TYPO3 Query builder.
With `$query->equals('pid', $pid);` I get entries with my pid.
And with `$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);` the default pid will be ignored.

And as the last step. My Controller gets the pid from the Settings, `unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['my_extension']['storagePid']);` an gives it to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would define this using TypoScript:

```
module.tx_yourextensionkey.persistence.storagePid = 123
```

Not being in a page context is not a blocker as long as you place the configuration on the first root TypoScript template (or include the TypoScript via other means which cause global inclusion not specific to any `sys_template` record or page tree location).

Comment: But the root page can not have TypoScript.

Comment: The root page (uid zero) cannot, true, but Extbase does not look there - it looks for the oldest `sys_template` record which has `is_root = 1` and as such it would find the oldest root template regardless of which page it exists on. Knowing this is by the way quite vital to correctly operating Extbase modules which use TypoScript that is provided as static templates (you must include these on the root template matching the criteria above)!

Comment: Still dosen't work. If i set in the TCA rootLevel = 1 and safe the record with pid = 0 it is working. But not with the TypoScript settings.

Comment: "it would find the oldest root template regardless of which page it exists on"  
this is not the case in TYPO8 and 9 anymore. It will take the first template found in the tree if it can't detect a currently selected pid.