# TYPO3 Upgrade 7.6 to 8.7 – missing powermail forms

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, powermail

I have upgraded an TYPO3 project from 7.6 to 8.7. Everything worked fine as far as I can tell.

Now I upgraded the powermail extension to the latest version and noticed that the form data is not "complete". I the frontend nearly everywhere it shows "no form to show". I the original TYPO3 instance we have 41 forms, in the dev project we only have 5 forms (in BE list and BE powermail form oveview) with different site and field counts than in the original 7.6 project. But when I check that in phpMyAdmin the tables are exact the same – all forms and fields are in the DB table. Also did a fresh import of the powermail tables – nothing changed.

Any idea why powermail does not show some of the forms?

Comment: you probably mess with the storagePid. maybe [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473246/typo3-extbase-set-storagepid-for-backend-module) can give you some hints.

Comment: I don't think so – 5 of the forms are available – but also not with all fields. Really strange thing...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of powermail in the past there was a change in database table names.
Look at https://gist.github.com/einpraegsam/a02bb69c29aa747de4ffb613704bbd7a

Comment: Thanks! These tables were already there (in the original project) but not complete – executed the sql queries and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my first upgrade attempt from 7.6 to 8.7 I lost all my forms and submitted messages, too. The second time when using the upgrade wizard, I only created or altered database tables but I did not perform any changes which would crop "unused tables" or rename or delete them. This time all forms and messages were saved.
Alexander Schaefer